# How to properly use populate in mongoose in NestJs?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I am using mongoose in NestJS, the problem is that when using populate it doesn't work, can I do something wrong ?

This is my scheme

```
import mongoose, {Document} from "mongoose";
import {Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory} from "@nestjs/mongoose";
import {User} from "../../users/entity/user.entity";
import {Product} from "../../products/entities/product.entity";


@Schema()
export class CartProduct extends Document {
    @Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product' })
    product: Product

    @Prop()
    color: string

    @Prop()
    size: string

    @Prop()
    quantity: number
}


@Schema({toJSON: {virtuals: true}, toObject: {virtuals: true}})
export class Cart extends Document {
    @Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', unique: true })
    user: User;

    @Prop()
    products: CartProduct[]
}

export const CartSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Cart)
```

And here I'm trying to populate

```
 async getAllCardProducts(userId: User['_id']) {
      const cart = await this.cartModel.findOne({user: userId}).populate('products.product')

      return cart.products  
    }
```

Trying to use populate

Answer (score 0):

You need to define type of `product` in `@Prop`

```
@Schema()
export class CartProduct extends Document {
    @Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product' })
    product: Product

    @Prop()
    color: string

    @Prop()
    size: string

    @Prop()
    quantity: number
}


@Schema({toJSON: {virtuals: true}, toObject: {virtuals: true}})
export class Cart extends Document {
    @Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', unique: true })
    user: User;

    @Prop({ type: [CartProduct] })
    products: CartProduct[]
}

export const CartSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Cart)
```